# Not getting response from localhost:9200

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have configured ElasticSearch on my pc, but when I tried to access localhost:9200, it isn't returning me the JSON object. I have configures Kibana and it is running fine on localhost:5601, but not getting JSON object in response from localhost:9200.

---

```
My elasticsearch.yml file:

    xpack.security.enabled: true
    xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true
    xpack.security.http.ssl:
      enabled: true
      keystore.path: certs/http.p12
    xpack.security.transport.ssl:
      enabled: true
      verification_mode: certificate
      keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
      truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
    http.host: [_local_, _site_]
    transport.host: [_local_, _site_]
```

Comment: which version of ES are you using?
And did you set username and password for your elasticsearch as you enabled `xpack.security.enabled`

Comment: Yes, I'd try querying `https://localhost:9200` and if you get a 401 back from that then you need to use the right credentials.